# Where are the save files located?

Tags: android, knights-of-pen-and-paper

I was hoping to transfer my Knights of Pen and Paper save information between multiple Android devices.  Does anyone know where I might find the relevant files?  My devices are rooted.

Comment: which version of android are you on?

Answer (score 5):

If they're storing them in their private data directory then it should be something like:

`/data/data/your.package/files` where `your.package` is the package name of the app.

If they're storing them in their external storage directory then it should be in:

`/sdcard/Android/data/your.package/files` where `sdcard` is your external storage device.

If they're not storing them in one of those places then it's in a custom file on the external storage device.

UPDATE: I believe the package name for the game is `br.com.beholdstudios.knightspp`

Comment: You must edit owner rights /data/data/your.package/files and set it to allow writes and reads before your copie the data.kopp file.

Answer (score 4):

Please note, that you have to have root access to get to this file.  When you plug your device into the computer, typically you won't be able to see the root directory of the device, instead you will see /sdcard

I'm not aware of a way to view the root directory of an android device using Windows Explorer (I know there's a way, I just don't know offhand)

If you gain root access, and use a file explorer, the file explorer will be able to traverse up to the root directory or /

There, you will be able to navigate to /data/data/br.com.beholdstudios.knightspp/files/data.kopp

Answer (score 3):

I found data.kopp under /data/data/br.com.beholdstudios.knightspp

I was able to copy it to my other device under that same folder path and it loaded up my chars+game on the other device.

I was using Root Browser and both devices were rooted.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be specific to Android 4.

Short answer: you won't be able to find them. The word from Paradox is:

> The save file is called "data.kopp", and should usually be located in
>   /data/app/br.com.beholdstudios.knightspp/files/
>
> However, it seems really hard to find on some devices, as it's a **Unity
>   compressed data file**. If you can find it, you should be able to
>   replace the new save file on your new device with the old file.

After spending about 20 minutes looking I was unable to find any file that was even close to that. Showing hidden files didn't help. I looked for any file named `data.kopp` and didn't find anything (except my old save file from the previous install, which would've helped if I knew where to put it to overwrite the new save).