# where is the save file located?

Tags: android, knights-of-pen-and-paper

Question is about KOPP +1 Edition, not KOPP.

[Where are the save files located?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/100221/where-are-the-save-files-located) -- this one didn't help. I bought KOPP+1 for my Android 2.3 device. Played it for a bit, made 3 save files. I just upgraded to an Android 4.2.2 device. I moved KOPP+1 over to the SD card and put the SD card in the new phone. When I open KOPP it can't find the save games. I've searched for files using the file browser named "knights" and not found any files. But searching for "seesmic" did find files, so I know that's working.

How can I find my old save file and get it working on my new phone?

Comment: @fbueckert you missed how I referenced that question. This is a different version of the game.

Comment: Looking through the Google App store, Knights of Pen and Paper is only available as the +1 version.  I don't believe there is, or was, any way to play it on Android in any other fashion beyond KOPP+1.  So that makes your question the same as the previous one, I think.

Comment: Ah. Well the previous question didn't help, so maybe it doesn't work for Android 4. Not sure. So far even the Paradox community manager hasn't been able to answer this. My suspicion is that because of Unity it's a compressed file with a funky name and I won't be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

If game is using private storage you will want to check:
/data/data/br.com.beholdstudios.knightspp/
or
/sdcard/Android/data/br.com.beholdstudios.knightspp/

Comment: Nope. I don't have either of those directories. I did manage to find the old save file: br.com.beholdstudios.knightspp-1.asec. I've moved that into my tmp directory. After moving it I am still able to open save files on the currently installed KOPP (which has about 10 minutes of play time in). So it's accessing the save file from somewhere still. There is only one file (the old save file) with behold in the name on the system.